# Make a single page landscape in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs

I have a really large table and I need to add it to a portrait document. Is there any way to make a *single page* landscape in Google Docs?

In Word you could add a "Section break" and do that. But I'm working on a document with my friend and I can't just use Word.

Comment: Not that I can see sorry buddy, I'm looking for the same solution. Source:
https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/formatting/oSSv-MZqzys

Comment: Have you found a work-a-round in the meantime or solution?

Comment: I use Google docs for its collaborative writing really. What I do is work with a draft version in Google docs and then export to word.  There's no real solution. Sad really,  I wish they could work to improve it, it's been really horrible so far in everything except collaboration.

Comment: Of course. You insert a section break and change the orientation.

Comment: You can upvote the feature request [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ElJ8Jp1O724).

Comment: @David there is no section break in google docs.

Comment: I had a similar issue with text that I wanted to fit all in one line, and what I ended up doing was adjusting the left and right margins and decreasing the font size a little to make it fit on one line. (I also wanted to change the one page to landscape and leave other pages in portrait, but this isn't currently possible, as other answers have pointed out.)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Currently a single Google Document can only be **either** Landscape or Portrait **not both**. Changing page orientation is done by selecting ***File*** and then ***Page setup...***
[image: Page Setup popup]

It is currently recommended to separate the Landscape and Portrait pages into different documents.

A good place to get more information that might help is at [Google Products Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/documents).

***Note:*** An additional option might be to have three files in Google Docs. The Portrait, The Landscape, and Microsoft Word Doc which integrates the two layouts into the correct sequence (this document would be *Read Only* when viewed in Google Docs).

A Microsoft Word document may allow multiple orientations of the Page Layout, but if it is converted to a Google Document the Page Layout for each page will revert to the first Orientation found in the document.

Also, creating multiple Orientations in Word isn't as straight forward as one might want either.

For those wanting to do this in Word:
**[Use portrait and landscape orientation in the same document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/rotate-page-orientation-between-portrait-and-landscape-in-word-2010-HA101852441.aspx)**

1. Select the pages or paragraphs that you want to change to portrait
   or landscape orientation.
   *NOTE*    If you select some but not all of
   the text on a page to change to portrait or landscape orientation,
   Word places the selected text on its own page, and the surrounding
   text on separate pages.
2. On the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Margins**.
   [image: Page Setup group]
3. Click **Custom Margins**. (This is the important part)
4. On the **Margins** tab, click **Portrait** or **Landscape**.
5. In the **Apply to** list, click **Selected text**..
   [image]

   *NOTE*    Microsoft Word automatically inserts section breaks before and after the text that has the new page orientation. If your document is already divided into sections, you can click in a section (or select multiple sections), and then change the orientation for only the sections that you select.

Comment: Is it possible to change from portrait mode to landscape mode using CLI ( command line interface)?

Comment: It is a bummer that this is the correct answer. There is no way to do it.

Comment: It seems like Google's closer to making this happen. There are sections now, and you can do page setup for different sections. But at the time I'm commenting, on the "whole document" section will allow changing page orientation.

Comment: Still unable to have different orientation in one document, a year later ...

Comment: This is not a correct answer. This just changes the whole document. No move on this in the past year from Google. This is a joke.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I knew this before wasting time pulling levers that are not connected.

Comment: This is not the answer! see @blami answer below..

Answer (score 11):

Updating this as it recently become possible to rotate sections and thus also individual pages in Google Docs.

There are two ways how to change orientation of just a single page in the document:

1. On page that already exists and which you want to change orientation of select something and go to *File -> Page Setup* and you should see selection box *Apply to*. Here select *Selected content* and choose desired orientation.
2. This option is very similar to MS Word and allows to change properties of entire section. Create section break starting on new page *Insert -> Break -> Section Break (Next Page)*. Then you can use *Format -> Page Orientation* or *File -> Page Setup* and choose section you've just created in the *Apply to* selection box. Choose desired orientation.

First option basically does same thing as second, behind scenes creates a new section and then applies orientation for that section.

If you don't see options above (particularly *Apply to* selection box) it might be because you are using corporate Google Workspaces/Apps with conservative new feature rollout policy and this feature wasn't rolled out to you yet. I tested above successfully on bare GMail account.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the OP.

Comment: I hope people find this one

Answer (score -3):

On the navigation bar at the top of the page where you have 'File, Edit, View, Insert etc' there is a tab called 'Help'. Type into that tab 'Page setup' and it will bring right away the options box which you can manipulate whichever way you like.

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, Page Setup sets the orientation for the entire document, not just a single page. "Page Setup" is located in the File menu; that you can also reach it from searching in Help is just a convenience.

Answer (score -3):

Just go to page setup and type your dimensions (portrait: 8.5 by 11)

Answer (score -6):

All you have to do is go to file, page setup, and then go to landscape.

Comment: This rotates _every_ page to landscape, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Vidar: Indeed it does. There is not currently a way to have pages with different orientation in a single Google Doc.