# How to set a single page's properties?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

The goal is to selectively configure a single page of a multi-page document to:

1. [landscape (hyperlink to similar, yet a subset of this question)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20258/make-a-single-page-landscape-in-google-documents) and
2. paper size A3.

The hope is that the link is dated and that the community has found solutions to enable implementation of the line-items.  If both are not possible for a single page, it would still be a 'win' if either was possible.

If this is not possible, I would encourage readers to send a feature request to Google and up vote the question to signal interest in the feature (maybe Google will take notice).

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not possible to change only one page in a Docs document.

Comment: if it is indeed true that it is not possible, then let's hope the talented developers at Google will take notice and respond with the feature

Comment: Send your feature request directly to Google from your Google document by clicking on Help > Report a problem.