# How to change the size of paper in Google Docs to custom size?

Tags: google-docs

I want to change the paper size in Google Docs document,
But you can only change to a few individual sizes from the list.

How do I change to a custom size?

**I need every page of a different size.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google Documents the page settings apply to the whole document, so if you need that every page have different size, you should use a different file for each page.

Related

- [Make a single page landscape in Google Documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20258/88163)

Answer (score 4):

I found out how to set custom size.

Although not every page of a different size as Rubén wrote that it is impossible, but also helped.

> you can customize the size of your paper using the add-on for Docs called Page Sizer. You can get it by going to Add-ons (in the tool bar) > Get add-ons and then searching for it by name.
>   Once you find it, just press the blue Free button to add it to Docs. You can then access it by clicking on Add-ons in the tool bar to display all the add-ons you have.

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4113696